# What is the process of updating your home address for your workplace?

Tags: human-resources, documentation, process

I plan on moving in the next few months to a different state but I will still be employed in the same company. I know this might vary with company, but in general what is the process involved in updating my home address with my company?

I know I need to update my W-4 for tax purposes and probably the address on file in company's HR Portal. Anything else besides this?

Will be asked to show proof of my new address? Usually when I join companies as a new employee I have never been asked for this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Workplace SE.. unfortunately I don't think we can answer this question for you since it deals with what processes your *specific* company has regarding address changes and without working there we can't really know. I'd suggest asking someone in HR if there is any specific process they want you to follow or documentation they will need,

Comment: This is very company specific.  You need to ask your HR folks on this one.  VTC

Answer (score 2):

> in general what is the process involved in updating my home address
>   with my company?

Contact HR. Tell them when you will be moving, and what will be your new address.

Every HR department has their own standard process for handling change of address. Most likely they will coordinate everything with their records and with Payroll. But they may ask you to contact Payroll directly.

This is not a big deal.

> Anything else besides this?

HR will tell you if they need anything else.

> Will be asked to show proof of my new address?

Probably not.

Comment: Before you commit to a move like this, make sure that your company will continue to employ you. Some companies only allow remote workers in states where they already have a presence. The reason for this in the US involves benefits and especially health insurance.  And some states have laws that require specific benefits that your home state may not.  They may not want to get into the legal considerations of figuring out what benefits you have to have if they have no one else in the state.

Comment: They may also want to adjust your compensation if you are moving to a cheaper locale. So if you are currently in NY and move to Missouri, you might expect they would not want to continue to pay a NY based salary. You might also need an upward adjustment if you were going the other way. And that might not be in the budget.